# Prestashop SQL modify table conditioned by another table

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

I need to change the value **out_of_stock** on products that are in **id_category_default** 52.
The problem is that the **out_of_stock** column in the BDD is on table **ps_stock_available** while the **id_category_default** is defined on tables **ps_product_shop** and **ps_product**
I know how to do this when the change is to be made directly on the same table, but no clue when the condition is depending on a different table.
Thanks!
Here is what I've tried to formulate so far:

> SELECT    p.ProducId,
>             s.ProductId
>   FROM      ps_produc p
>   JOIN      ps_stock_available s
>   ON        p.product_id = s.product_id
>   UPDATE    ps_stock_available
>   SET       available_for_order = 1
>   WHERE     id_category_default = 52;

Comment: But where are you doing it? Could you paste your code?

Comment: I'm trying to do a SQL query, this is what I've tried to formulate so far:
SELECT    p.ProducId,
          s.ProductId
FROM      ps_produc p
JOIN      ps_stock_available s
ON        p.product_id = s.product_id
UPDATE    ps_stock_available
SET       available_for_order = 1
WHERE     id_category_default = 52;